# Specify font size of footnotes

Tags: footnotes, fontsize

I can choose an individual font size in pt with

```
\usepackage[fontsize=9.25pt]{scrextend}
```

If I want a bigger font size for the footnotes, one way is to set

```
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
```

Is there a way, without using additional packages, to specify an individual font size in pt for footnotes?

Comment: replace `\small` with `\fontsize{2cm}{2.5cm}\selectfont`

Comment: I'd rather give two numbers in pt, but that does indeed the trick. I'll have to do the math what the default `\footnotesize` is after setting an individual fontsize.

Comment: you can of course use `pt` I just used 2cm to make sure you noticed the effect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See David's comment: Replace `\small` with `\fontsize{2cm}{2.5cm}\selectfont` (the `2cm` is just to show the effect, choose the size that you like such as `4pt` etc.).